# Would it be possible for a surface mounted capacitor (decoupling) to power on a CPU core?

Tags: cpu, decoupling-capacitor

My question is simple: could a decoupling capacitor be designed in such a way that it could in theory power on a CPU core?

Do these types of capacitors have sufficient power to power on a core without changes to the design?

Comment: When your CPU suddenly starts processing and demands more current than the supply can handle the decoupling capacitors do power it for a few nanoseconds. After that you need external power.

Comment: Capacitors don't "have power" so I think you need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Nope. Decoupling capacitors are far, far too tiny to run a CPU for any useful amount of time. You can put a supercap on there but that would not be the small size and footprint of a capacitor originally selected to decouple the power supply. Please edit your question and explain the actual problem you're trying to solve. As it's written, this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Then would it be possible for a decoupling capacitor to provide just enough current to power a transistor switch to a on and off position ? So that when more power (current) is required (when processing demands increase) the switch is opened (i.e. placed in a on position). Does this sound plausible ?

Answer (score 2):

One can put energy into a capacitor and then briefly power something from it.  You can easily confirm this by charging up a capacitor to a few volts and then placing an LED and resistor across it.

The basic equation for a capacitor is...

$$I=C\frac{dv}{dt} $$

And also

Q = C * V or alternately (Charge = Capacitance * Voltage)

**SMALL MCU ON BULK CAPACITOR:**

So, for example, if I have a small microcontroller that is drawing 1mA and its drawing power from a 1mF bulk capacitor then the voltage on the capacitor will drop by...

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{I}{C} = \frac{1mA}{1mF} = \frac{1V}{s} $$

If the capacitor was initially charged to 5V and the microcontroller had an operating voltage range of 2.5V to 5.0V then it could run for 2.5 seconds before the capacitor voltage went too low to power it any more.

**SMALL MCU ON 1UF DECOUPLING CAPACITOR:**

In the case of say a 1uF SMT ceramic decoupling capacitor.  Then the microcontroller runs for...

$$\frac{(5V - 2.5V) * 1uF}{1mA} = 2.5ms$$

There are actually cases (like energy harvesting) where an MCU sleeps for a long time, wakes up for a few ms to take a sensor reading, and then goes back to sleep.  So even this short timescale can be useful.

**SMALL MCU ON SUPER CAPACITOR:**

If we wanted to run for a long time on a capacitor we might use something like a [5F super capacitor pack](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/cornell-dubilier-illinois-capacitor/DGH505Q5R5/7387525), then we can power the MCU for something like 12500 seconds (3.47 hours).  Although this falls outside the realm of a "decoupling" capacitor.  This type of setup is useful for things like solar powered sensors that need to charge up every day and operate through the night.  Compared to batteries, which have a limited number of charge cycles, capacitors can be charged and discharged thousands of times with no problems, and they are often rated to work at colder temperatures than standard batteries.

**HIGH WATTAGE CPU:**

If on the other hand you are powering something like an intel CPU that draws like 100W, then a standard decoupling capacitor is only going to power it for nanoseconds.  Even a very large capacitor is only going to last milliseconds before the voltage goes out of the specified operating range.

Note that capacitors don't generate power.  They only store power that's put into them.

Comment: That's not a using a decoupling capacitor or replacing one, though. A 1000uF capacitor or a supercap not be the small size and footprint of capacitor originally selected just to decouple the power supply, however far up cables its come. This is more a general explanation of capacitor discharging so downvoted as it doesn't answer the question as asked I'm afraid, though it's not a good and clear question anyway.

Comment: @TonyM You are correct.  1000uF would typically be considered the bulk capacitor for a power supply rather than "decoupling".  Based on the question I am skeptical that the OP really knows what a decoupling capacitor actually is.  So instead, I answered the more general question:  Could one power a processor of some type (and for how long) from some capacitors of various sizes.  I will add an example for 1uF if its more appropriate.

Comment: I've removed my DV because, with your edits, I think you've done the best you could with the question you had.

Answer (score -1):

> Would it be possible for a Surface Mounted Capacitor (Decoupling) to Power on a CPU core?

There's nothing theoretical about it. **Those capacitors already do it**! The output impedance of the power supply is too high to maintain adequate supply voltage during the very fast current spikes demanded by powerful CPUs. So, for fractions of a millisecond, *the capacitors deliver most of the power to the CPU*, until the power supply gets a chance to recharge them.

The ceramic decoupling capacitors on and around the CPU are sized to only have enough energy for fractions of a millisecond, of course. If you wanted to power the core for longer than that, you'd need an external backup capacitor - or a few - and a switching power converter to efficiently extract most of the energy from the capacitor.

Surprise, surprise: that's what any switching power supply in a PC already does! If you unplug the mains for a couple of mains line cycles, the power supply will be discharging the DC-link capacitors and powering the CPU cores.

Now, DC-link capacitors aren't usually considered "decoupling" capacitors, but they serve the same function - just at a much longer timescale: milliseconds vs. microseconds. And they aren't surface-mount, but if you really wanted to, you could split the DC-link capacitor into several smaller SMT parts. It'd cost more, but there's nothing fundamentally preventing that.

So, I'd say that the answer to your question is a qualified **yes**: that's how CPUs already work. Without decoupling capacitors, they'd literally lose supply power and reset.

Comment: The OP's written a vague question and I think this answer is just a rather stretched interpretation of one view of it. Besides that, it's all phrased a bit extreme. For instance, CPUs would not lose power and reset, literally or otherwise, as thousands of MCU designs show with bad practice.